# Animating a button to move to top

Tags: android, animation

I want to animate a button such that it moves from `android:gravity="centre"` to `android:gravity="top"`. Any suggestions as to how can I achieve this. I'm still new to android so please provide some code as well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you have to use translate animation: here is the android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html

And a nice tutorial: http://iserveandroid.blogspot.ch/2010/12/slide-up-down-translate.html

Try to use the tutorial, if you have more specific programing questions, please edit your answer and I will help you.